# How to make the battery monitor more accurate?

Tags: 16.04, laptop, battery

I've got a Thinkpad T730, purchased refurbed, with new battery, a week ago.  I'm running Ubuntu MATE 16.04.3 LTS.  I've noted that the battery monitor (in the top panel, by default) gives both a percentage and an expected time remaining -- but the time remaining is wildly optimistic.  With a fully charged (stock, 6-cell) battery, it'll report available working time around five hours, when in fact, even with fairly aggressive power saving, I only get around three hours (and with heavy consumption, less than an hour, but that's less of a problem, since I *know* the estimate won't be accurate with 100% CPU load).

Aside from running the battery through additional charge/discharge cycles to calibrate the readings, is there a way to make the time estimate a little closer to the real world running time?

Comment: You have to discharge the battery ALL THE WAY at least once, and then also give the battery monitor some time to accumulate enough statistics about the battery use, for it to be more accurate.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been using rechargeable batteries long enough to remember that as *bad* for lead-acid and NiCd types -- and of course Li-ion powered devices shut down at around 1.0 V/cell, they don't let them go down to zero anyway.  I'll try running it all the way down and see what I get.